# Calling specific table section and row for alternate segue? (programmatically)

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am having an issue with calling a specific table section and row using dynamic cells. The table has a navigation controller embedded within it and existing cells use a segue titled 'detailSegue' to 'LibraryViewController'. I would like for a specific cell section and row to redirect to an alternate view controller with a segue titled 'webSegue' to 'WebViewController'.

This is my current code:

```
class LibraryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var selectedFileName = ""

    struct Objects {
        var sectionName : String
        var sectionObjects : [String]
        var sectionImages : [String]
    }

    var objectArray = [Objects]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        objectArray = [Objects(sectionName: "Led Zeppelin", sectionObjects: ["Houses Of The Holy", "Physical Graffiti", "Presence"], sectionImages: ["Houses Of The Holy", "Physical Graffiti", "Presence"]),
                       Objects(sectionName: "Dave Matthews Band", sectionObjects: ["Crash", "Before These Crowded Streets", "Everyday"], sectionImages: ["Crash", "Before These Crowded Streets", "Everyday"]),
                       Objects(sectionName: "Drake", sectionObjects: ["Scorpion", "Views", "So Far Gone"], sectionImages: ["Scorpion", "Views", "So Far Gone"]),
                       Objects(sectionName: "Jay-Z", sectionObjects: ["The Black Album", "American Gangster", "The Blueprint"], sectionImages: ["The Black Album", "American Gangster", "The Blueprint"]),
                       Objects(sectionName: "Others", sectionObjects: ["Other Albums", "User Guide"], sectionImages: ["Other Albums", "User Guide"])
        ]
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return objectArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "libraryCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionImages[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return objectArray[section].sectionName
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedFileName = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]
        if indexPath.section == 4 && indexPath.row == 1
        {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "webSegue", sender: self)
        }
        else
        {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
        }
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        let objLibraryViewController = segue.destination as! LibraryViewController
        objLibraryViewController.fileName = selectedFileName
        }

}
```

I have instituted an 'if' statement in 'didSelectRow';

```
if indexPath.section == 4 && indexPath.row == 1
        {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "webSegue", sender: self)
        }
        else
        {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "detailSegue", sender: self)
        }
```

yet the particular cell I am calling still uses the 'detailSegue' that brings me to the LibraryViewController.

The only cell that I need redirected is the "Other Albums" cell which happens to be the 4th section and 1st row.

What am i missing that causes the segue to my WebViewController to disregarded?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, What am i missing that causes the segue to my WebViewController to disregarded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to distinguish the segues also in `prepare(for`, the *web* segue is performed without changes.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detailSegue" {
        let objLibraryViewController = segue.destination as! LibraryViewController
        objLibraryViewController.fileName = selectedFileName
    }
}
```

Comment: I get error: "Initialization of immutable value 'webViewController' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it"  on line : `code`"let webViewController = segue.destination as! WebViewController" `/code`  and segues is disregarded.

Comment: Yes, of course. Please note the next line. Use the reference to pass data to `webViewController`. If you don't need to pass anything to the web view controller delete this line and the `case "webSegue":` line.

Comment: I dont need to pass any data, just need to redirect view. So I delete the: "case "webSegue" line and recieve the same error.

Comment: I updated the answer. Now only the `detailSegue` is considered to pass the data, the other segue is performed directly.

Comment: Tried, however, segue is still disregarded, maybe the cell identifier?

Comment: Rather the segue identifier.

Comment: Correct, the segue identifier. My error was quite simple and admittedly 'dumb' I simply miscounted the number of rows. Forgot to start row count at '0'. Thanks for your expertise again!